# pdb/ipdb for python break on editable condition

Tags: python, pdb

Say I have code the following code:

```
for i in range(100):
    print i
```

In general I can add one line to the code as:

```
for i in range(100):
    import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()
    print i
```

However, now I want to debug it at condition of `i == 10`, and I don't want to bother by typing `c` for 10 times in ipdb, how should I do?

In the documentation I found `condition bpnumber [condition]`, but how could I know the `bpnumber` if there is no list of `bpnumber` index. The documentation also says `b(reak) ([file:]lineno | function) [, condition]`. For example, assume the line number of `print i` is `xx`. I entered the following in ipdb shell: `b xx, i == 10` but nothing as expected happened.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I did some exploration myself, here is my new understanding of `pdb`.

When you input `import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()` you actually add an entry point of `ipdb` to the line, not really a breakpoint.

After you enter `ipdb`, you can then set up breakpoints.

So, to realize what I want for conditional debugging, I should do this:

```
import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()
for i in range(100):
    print i
```

then after I enter `ipdb`, I can input `b xx, i == 10`, and then `c` or `r` to run the code. The code will stop when the condition is met.

When I input `l`, the `bpnumber` is shown for the line as :

```
          xx-1                  for i in range(100): 
bpnumber> xx                        print i
          xx+1                      ...
```

I have to say, the documentation and all other explanations are very confusing, I hope my answer here clarifies the difference between the "debug entry point" and "debug breakpoint"

Comment: @Rugnar xx means the line number as shown on the left

Answer (score 12):

There's a quick dirty way like this:

```
for i in range(100):
    if i == 10: import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()
    print i
```

It works and don't have to busy your mind with any other commands :)

Comment: well, i agree, but that is too invasive to the code, i have to change the code time to time if i want to change the condition

Comment: Ok but think about it, I edited my code to leave it in just one line of code. Is just as invasive as `import pdb;ipdb.set_trace()` don't you think. Though I agree would be useful to use `condition` but I can't seem to find any reference about how to use it.

Comment: say, if you already in the pdb, and you could not find any issue for `i==10`, but you want to try `i==50`, if you can not set up conditional breakpoint, you have to exit() pdb, modify the code to `if i==50:` and run it again. that is not user-friendly... anyway, thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 11):

I think you were looking for a more direct solution that did not involve adding lines to the code, and just involved debugger commands.

Your original example of

```
b xx, i == 10
```

doesn't work, because you are setting a breakpoint at the place in your code you inserted the ipdb.set_trace() command.  By adding the statement 'b xx, i == 10' in the debugger, you actually have 2 break points (1 conditional and 1 unconditional) defined at the same location (assuming xx is the line were the set_trace() command is).

Alternatively, once you have defined breakpoints in your code using the 'b' command, which apparently works for you.  You can add a condition to the breakpoint by

```
condition bpnumber boolean-expression
```

for example

```
condition 1 i == 10
```

Note: the bpnumber is the number assigned to the breakpoint, not the line in your code.  To see a list of breakpoints, just type 'b' with no arguments.

Also, if you want to enter debug mode without using ipdb.set_trace(), you simply run your code with the pdb/ipbd module enabled

```
python -m pdb foo.py
```