# Break when variable is a certain value when debugging with IPython?

Tags: python, debugging, ipython, pdb

Can I ask IPython to break when it encounters a variable at a specific value?

myloop.py

```
for myvar in range(1, 10):
    print("myvar: {}".format(myvar))
```

this does not work, but I envision something like...

```
%run -d -b myvar:6 /path/to/myloop.py
```

where IPython breaks when myvar is 6

There is a similar question using [`import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280575/pdb-ipdb-for-python-break-on-editable-condition) but based on IPython's [%run](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-run) all necessary input to debug a condition can be handled using the magic command.

Comment: I have provided an answer below, if my answer has helped you and you think it will help others who may follow this question please mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pdb/ipdb for python break on editable condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280575/pdb-ipdb-for-python-break-on-editable-condition)

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple:

```
for myvar in range(1, 10):
    if myvar == 6:
        print("myvar: {}".format(myvar))
```

Comment: This would require internal edits, which would be slow to add and cause unnecessary changes in version control.  Looking for a solution using %run.